# Text processing using awk when separator is part of word?

Tags: linux, awk, text-processing

I have a CSV file included 11 columns with the similar content

```
 SE Australia|PRM|2017-09-07T16:11:33|2641|-5537383165259899960|2017-09-07T16:12:17|"AU en2|networking-locator"|-|SC7_Electricians_Installer (only provides labor)|p-0715125|1
```

I am trying to use awk for separating each column, The problem is that in some sentences among 10 million records, the separator(pip) is part of the word. As you can see in below, pip is included in text **"AU en2|networking-locator"**. Using the following command returns a wrong info.

**`awk -F "|" '{print $4"_"$6"_"$7"_"$10}'`**

The result

```
2641_2017-09-07T16:12:17_"AU en2_p-0715125
```

The excepted result,

```
2641_2017-09-07T16:12:17_"AU en2|networking-locator"_p-0715125
```

As you see **AU en**2 considered as a separate column, however, is part of **AU en2|networking-locator**.  How can I change awk command in order to cover those columns?

Comment: Your sample Input and sample output is NOT clear? Please post them more clearly with CODE TAGS and let me know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I make it clear.

Comment: Kindly check my code now and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: @EdMorton it was a mistake, I have edited. sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You need GNU awk for that. With `gawk` you can use the [`FPAT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) variable:

```
gawk '{print $4,$6,$7,$10}' OFS=_ FPAT='"[^"]+"|[^|]+' file
```

Using `FPAT` you can tell awk how a field looks like instead of being limited to specify a field delimiter.

In the above example we are telling that a field is either a `"` followed by one ore more non `"` chars and a closing `"` *or* a sequence of non `|` chars. Those rules will be evaluated in order which gives the first a higher precedence.

Output:

```
2641_2017-09-07T16:12:17_"AU en2|networking-locator"_p-0715125
```

---

PS: The above solution is slower than splitting by a fixed char. As your file is 100 million lines long it might take very long to process.

If the file contains the `"abc|xyz"` fields only on position $7 *and* it is safe that in this situations there is just a single | in $7, then you can use this hack:

```
awk -F\| '$7~/"/{$7=$7"|"$8;$10=$11}{print $4,$6,$7,$10}' OFS=_ file
```

It should be much faster than the above solution but it works only under the mentioned circumstances. You have been warned!.

Comment: It looks awk using this parameter works very slowly with a huge amount of data. I have started the command since 20 min ago and still is working. with awk, the same file will process in 3 min.

Comment: Sure, it requires more effort to split by a complex regex than splitting by a fixed char. You'll have to wait (independently of the programming language you use and awk is already pretty fast) If you can change the process, make sure that you use a field delimiter which is not part of the data.

Comment: @MaryamPashmi I added a faster solution. But please check the requirements for it.

Comment: The first one might be a little faster if you set OFS and use commas between output fields rather than using string concatenation (a slow operation) with hard-coded underscores.

Comment: Good point! Changed...